# Accessing optional parameters from spring in angular

Tags: spring, angular, rest, service

I have a spring controller that gets order list and can also get a filtered list from input dates, below is my controller using util.Date

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/orders")
    public final Collection<OrderDto> getOrders(
            @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false)
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") final Date start,

            @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false)
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") final Date end) {
        LOGGER.debug("getOrders()");

        Collection<Order> orders = orderService.getAllOrders(start, end);
        return mappingService.map(orders, OrderDto.class);
    }
```

My angular services did not accept dates do i used strings

```
getOrders(from: string, to: string): Observable<Order[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams();

    if (from) {
      params.set('start', from);
    }

    if (to) {
      params.set('end', to);
    }
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl , { params: params })
      .pipe(map(this.extractData),
           tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
          catchError(this.handleError)
         );
  }
```

**baseUrl** looks like this and filtered url is what it should look like as i have tested the url on postman with actual dates and it worked

```
baseUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders';

  filterUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders?start=?&end=?';
```

**In my component**

```
 orders: Observable<Array<Order>>;
  start: string;
  end: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.orders = this.getOrders();
  }

  private getOrders() {
    return this.orderService.getOrders(this.start, this.end)
  }
```

**Note** i got zero response when i used one method not even on console and i think its as a result of the strings i used for the dates and date format in spring

Also It worked fine when i used two seperate two service method one with baseUrl and other with filteredUrl, only issue is i think it does not follow the rest standard or convention , i should be able to do it in one method